# Boltzmann distribution in spectroscopy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spectroscopy

If I understand correctly, the Boltzmann distribution in statistical mechanics gives us an idea of what the ratio of population of atoms between two energy states within an atom will be at a given temperature given the energy difference between the two states.

I was reading a source on spectroscopy, and it asks to calculate (using the boltzmann distribution law) what the ratio of population in the ground and excited states will be after an absorption of radiation of frequency 500 MHz radiation at 298 K.

My question is, is it not the population ratio **prior** to absorption that the Boltzmann distribution tells us? is it not incorrect to apply the boltzmann distribution to determine the population ratio of the two states after absorption?

I appreciate your help.